# Failed to resolve Gradle Mail dependency

Tags: spring-boot

The following error comes every time I try to build my Spring Boot Project (using Gradle 6.5):

```
    Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
 Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
    Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.3.0.RELEASE.
     Required by:
         project :
       Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.3.0.RELEASE.
          Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-mail/2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-mail-2.3.0.RELEASE.pom
             Content is not allowed in prolog.
    Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.3.0.RELEASE.
     Required by:
         project :  org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.3.0.RELEASE > org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE
       Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.3.0.RELEASE.
          Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-mail/2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-mail-2.3.0.RELEASE.pom
             Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

I work in a team and nobody else has the same error an it seems like we all have done the same things. I tried manually setting a library to javax.mail.jar that I've downloaded from the Oracle website but it did not help. The following line is from the build.gradle file where the dependency is added:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is the gradle cache interfering here? Are all your compile time dependencies downloaded properly?

Comment: It does not seem so. Firstly, the project runs on other devices without problems. Secondly, I have tried to delete gradle cache. No luck.